# Lyx problem with generating pdf

Tags: errors, lyx

I have installed the newest versions of Lyx and MikTeX.
When I try to make a pdf of ANY document I get the message like on the image.
Does someone know the solution?
When I click on Show output Anyway I can see the pdf file, but it is very tiring and annoying.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the complete code of a minimal example reproducing the error message?

Comment: I have just entered one word. Nothing else.

Comment: Yes, but behind the scene, there is a full latex code, beginning with `\documentclass`  and ending with `\end{document}`. it's this code we need to see what's happening.

Comment: This is what I get when export from Lyx to Latex(Plain):

%% LyX 2.3.6.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.

%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}

Comment: And what's the undefined control sequence mentioned by the log file? Compiling this code just produces a warning.

Comment: Where can I see that in Lyx?

Comment: I don't know – I don't use LyX. Probably in the same directory as the latex code, or one of its subdirectories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128701/discussion-between-johnb-and-bernard).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I updated MikTex both in administrator and user mode.